# How do you apply dynamic styling based on data from a helper in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I seem to run into this problem relatively often...I have a web UI element that needs to be styled differently depending on some underlying data. The entire UI element's data is populated via a helper like this:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    info: function() {
        return Session.get('data');
    }
});
```

And the data structure looks like this:

```
{
    invoicePaid: true,
    invoiceAmount: 100
    status: 'complete'
}
```

If I want this data to be styled, I have been doing this:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    info: function() {
        var result = Session.get('data');
        if (result.invoicePaid) {
            result.invoicePaidStyle = 'primary';
        } else if {
            result.invoicePaidStyle = 'danger';
        }
        etc.....
        return result;
    }
});
```

Obviously on the template I have `{{invoicePaidStyle}}` in the class list. This feels a bit clunky though...are there any better methods for decorating data that is returned to a template from a helper in Meteor?

Answer (score 3):

Think of the template as the view and the helpers as the controller. Then just do the decoration in the template itself:

```
<template name="foo">
  <div class="{{#if info.invoicePaid}}primary{{else}}danger{{/if}}">
    blah blah
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I like that style, thanks! Is it possible to wrap the opening <div> tag in the `#if` or will that blow up in meteor?

Comment: Sure, you can do that too. I find that can be more complicated then though because then you have to have an else for the whole div and usually the content is repeated.

Comment: I should add that you can't wrap an opening or closing tag without including the matching tag in the wrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    info: function() {
      return Session.get('data');
    },
    invoicePaidStyle: function (invoicePaid) {
        return invoicePaid ? 'primary' : 'danger';       
    }
});
```

And then in your HTML, do something like this.

```
{{invoicePaidStyle info.invoicePaid}}
```

I haven't tested this, but I generally do something similar.